# saving key and value pairs swift

Tags: swift, key-value

I need a way to save key and value pairs in swift for my application. I am new to IOS programming, but I know Android and I am looking for something like shared preferences in android, but for swift. By "save," I mean that when the user quits out of the application, the key and value pairs are saved in the local data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Swift 3.0

Saving Data:

```
   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
   userDefaults.set(yourKey, forKey: "yourKey")
   userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Reading Data:

```
 if let yourVariable: AnyObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "yourKey") as AnyObject? { }
```

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is no longer necessary. From the official documentation: `This is no longer necessary.` ;-)

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is called "Userdefaults" - you can use them like this:

Saving Data:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(variable, forKey: "yourKey")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Reading Data:

```
if let yourVariable: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") {
....
```

Here you find more information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: What does .synchronize() do ? - I have never done that before and it hasn't caused me any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Working way for Swift 3+:

```
// Storing values
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "KeyName") // Bool
UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "KeyName")  // Integer
UserDefaults.standard.set("TEST", forKey: "KeyName") // setObject

// Retrieving values
 UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "KeyName")
 UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "KeyName")
 UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "KeyName")

// Removing values
 UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "KeyName")
```